# Handle paragraphs in swift

Tags: swift, macos, label, nstextview, paragraph

Is there a recommended way of handling paragraphs in swift? I am very new to swift so I'm not sure what the recommended solution or any solution for that matter is.

I want to be able to open a .txt file and be able to select a paragraph, selecting the paragraph needs to print the selected paragraph to a label.

I haven't got any code for this yet, other than opening and viewing the text file by doing the following:

```
    let file = "/Users/wade/Desktop/ht.txt"
    let path=URL(fileURLWithPath: file)
    let text=try! String(contentsOf: path)
    textView.stringValue = text
```

Once the .txt file is displayed I want to be able to click on a paragraph and have the paragraph display in a separate label

I am not fixed on using .txt files if there is a better format for achieving this

I'm guessing that printing to the label should be as easy as

```
 let selectedParagraph = //however we identify the paragraph stringvalue

 let thelabel = selectedParagraph.stringValue
```

But I need to know how to identify and get the text from the paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subsclass of [NSTextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview) and use it to display the whole text. This will always select text by paragraph:

```
class ParagraphTextView: NSTextView {

    override func selectionRange(forProposedRange proposedCharRange: NSRange,
                                 granularity: NSSelectionGranularity) -> NSRange {

        return super.selectionRange(forProposedRange: proposedCharRange,
                                    granularity: .selectByParagraph)
    }

}
```

Then set a delegate ([NSTextViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextviewdelegate)) and track selection changes of the text view to update your secondary label with the current selection.

Comment: Is this correct?
'class ParagraphTextView: NSTextView {
            override func selectionRange(forProposedRange proposedCharRange: NSRange,
                                         granularity: NSSelectionGranularity) -> NSRange {
                return super.selectionRange(forProposedRange: proposedCharRange,
                granularity: .selectByParagraph)
                let file = "/Users/wade/Desktop/ht.txt"
                let path=URL(fileURLWithPath: file)
                let text=try! String(contentsOf: path)
                textView.stringValue = text }'

Comment: Not sure why that isn't formatting as code.. 

textView.StringValue = text returns the following error

Class declaration cannot close over value 'self' defined in outer scope

Comment: @wades set the contents of the textview elsewhere in the code. E.g. in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: Okay I have that setup and running but it not selecting paragraphs on click

Comment: @wades the text view should be set as selectable, but not editable in Interface Builder. Also set a breakpoint in the `selectionRange` to see if it’s actually called.

Comment: I've used a breakpoint to see if its being called, doesn't look like it is. I must have done something wrong

Comment: Select the text view in Interface Builder, select “Identity Inspector” and make sure the custom class is set to `ParagraphTextView`.